# What is the relation between a filter matrix and convolution Fourier basis?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convolution

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218064/why-convolution-in-spatial-domain-equal-to-multiplication-in-frequency-domain) which is about why convolution is equal to multiplication in the frequency domain. But I can't get the second part of the answer. Is every transform equal to a new frequency domain? and is convolution equal to multiplication in every other domain? I can't get what is the relation between filter, eigenvector-eigenvalue and convolution in the mentioned answer. Could you please a little explain about it? Thanks